# How do I use dot notation in order to create memory cups to store values?

Tags: javascript

I want to store the audio elements and audio array names in each index of audiochannel, the array, that is created. I remember my teacher using this method of creating memory cups with a ".". Like temp.xSpd. How do I create memory cups, or I think its also object fields, to properly store the data?

```
var audioArray=[];
var audiochannels=[];
var audioArrayNames=["ring","splat"];

for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    audioArray[i]=document.getElementById("audio"+i);
}

for(var a=0;a<2;a++){
    audiochannels[a] = {};
    audiochannels[a].channel = new Audio();
    audiochannels[a].channel.name=audioArrayNames[a];
    audiochannel[a].channel.src=audioArray[a];
        
    console.log(audiochannels[a].channel.name);
    console.log(audiochannels[a].channel.src);
}
```

```
<audio id='audio0' src='ring.wav' preload='auto'></audio>
<audio id='audio1' src='splat.wav' preload='auto'></audio>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just set ``audiochannels[a] = new Audio()`` if the only field in ``audiochannels[a]`` is the ``channel`` field. Then you could just update ``auidiochannels[a].name`` and ``audiochannels[a].src`` as ``audiochannels[a]`` would be your ``Audio`` object

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? (Also, you seem to have a typo of `audiochannel` rather than `audiochannels` in your second loop)

Comment: I didn't notice typo. I thought my coding logic was wrong.

Comment: @Strollas Did that typo solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did. The issue was the typo.